# While Loop condition with an if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

Problem: Define a function fizzBuzz(max) that takes a number and prints every number from 0 to max (not inclusive) that is divisible by 3.

For the above question, I'm not sure why when I use the `while` loop as below it doesn't work but I need to add another `if` conditional statement.

**Does not work**

```js
let i=0;
while (i<max && i%3===0) {
    console.log (i);
    i++;
}
```

**Works**

```js
let i=0;
while (i<max) {
    if (i%3===0) {
        console.log (i);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Aside: you haven't created a `FizzBuzz` function which is the first thing the question asks you to do.

Comment: The condition given to `while` indicates when the loop should continue to loop. The condition in an `if` does not determine whether the loop continues or not. Even when the `if` condition is false, the loop can still make another iteration. On the other hand, when the `while` condition is false, the loop exits.

Comment: There are two unrelated conditions - i is less than max (keep going) and i is a multiple of 3 (display it).

Answer (score 1):

The two snippets you provided aren't equivalent. Once the condition of the `while` loop isn't met, the loop terminates. So, in the first snippet, after printing out `0`, the loop's condition evaluates `1`, finds the condition to be `false` (since `1%3` is `1`, not `0`), and terminates the loop. In the second snippet, the loop continues iterating until `i` is equal to `max`, and the `if` condition inside it is in charge of determining whether `i` needs to be printed or not.

Side note #1:
Since you know `0` is divisible by `3`, you could increment in steps of `3` to just get all the numbers divisible by `3` instead of checking all the numbers in between:

```js
let i = 0;
while (i < max) {
    console.log (i);
    i += 3;
}
```

Side note #2:
This is probably a matter of style, but since the body of the only effect the body of the loop has on the condition is a fixed increment of `i`, a `for` loop feels more appropriate, at least to me:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < max; i += 3) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop doesn't work because it breaks when `i === 1` since `1%3 !== 0` and `i<max && i%3===0` is `false`.

Your second code snippet solves that problem.

There's also an option to use a functional one-liner and generate a fake array and print its indices multiplied by `3`:

```js
const max = 40;

Array.from({length: Math.ceil(max / 3)}, (_, i) => console.log(i * 3));
```